# PHP numbering by unique ID grouping

Tags: php, mysql, loops, web

I want to auto numbering but by user group

Query :

```
$query = "select distinct(DATE_FORMAT(a.in_time, '%Y%m%d')) as in_time, a.user_id, a.notes, b.nama from attendance a left join dat_login b on(a.user_id=b.ID) where DATE_FORMAT(a.in_time, '%Y')='2017' and DATE_FORMAT(a.in_time, '%M')='April' and id_shop!=2 order by b.nama asc";
$querynm = "select distinct(b.nama) as nama from attendance a left join dat_login b on(a.user_id=b.ID) where DATE_FORMAT(a.in_time, '%Y')='2017' and DATE_FORMAT(a.in_time, '%M')='April' group by b.nama order by b.nama asc";
$stid = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
$stnm = mysqli_query($conn, $querynm) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

Result :

```
$alphabet_start = 'A';
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
$data['user_id'] += 1;
$no_cell = 11;
echo $data['nama'] . " ";
echo $data['user_id'] . " ";
  if ($data['notes']=="") {
    echo chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . $no_cell . " - " . chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . ". " . "Masuk <br>";
  } else if ($data['notes']=="S") {
    echo chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . $no_cell . " - " . chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . ". " . "Sakit <br>";
  } else if ($data['notes']=="L") {
    echo chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . $no_cell . " - " . chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . ". " . "Libur <br>";
  }
$alphabet_start++;
$no_cell++;
$data['user_id']++;
}
```

But, the value showing like this :

[image]

I want the value showing like this :

[image]

As you can see the number is changing in the next name, how to do it ?
Sorry for my bad grammar. Thanks before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing but I think I understand what you mean.
You can do it as such:

```
$alphabet_start = 'A';
$userID = "";
$cells = array();
$cellNum = 11;

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
    $data['user_id'] += 1;

    if (in_array($data['user_id'], $cells)) {
        $no_cell = $cellNum;
    } else {
        $no_cell = ($cellNum += 1);
        $cells[] = $data['user_id'];
    }

    echo $data['nama'] . " ";
    echo $data['user_id'] . " ";
    if ($data['notes'] == "") {
        echo chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . $no_cell . " - " . chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . ". " . "Masuk <br>";
    } else if ($data['notes'] == "S") {
        echo chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . $no_cell . " - " . chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . ". " . "Sakit <br>";
    } else if ($data['notes'] == "L") {
        echo chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . $no_cell . " - " . chr(ord("A") + date('d', strtotime($data['in_time']))) . ". " . "Libur <br>";
    }
    $alphabet_start++;
    $no_cell++;
    $data['user_id']++;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer mr. styl3r, but the user_id values is get from the database and the first value is not always 52, and the user_id values is very much. i can't do it one by one in switch case.

Comment: How do you plan to increment the `$no_cell`?

Comment: $no_cell incrementing in each name, one number for one name

Comment: May I know what exactly you're trying to create? Maybe I can rewrite the script for you.

Comment: I want to make an absence report, but the present information isn't in one line of the name [link](https://scontent-sin6-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/18157315_408667252850978_4781416262584115337_n.jpg?oh=4f9a42c7e624fd471c6c578f3ebcd5c8&oe=59755078), and i want the present information in one line of the name like this [link](https://scontent-sin6-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17992077_408666979517672_4209817175543116115_n.jpg?oh=e2b2bef2fd843ab5836ca230c75dba87&oe=597ADE5F)

Comment: Alright I get it now. I'll re-write the code and update my answer.

Comment: Updated. I didn't test it but I think it should work perfectly

Comment: thanks mr. styl3r, your code is success but there's a bit mistake, i change
$cellNum = 11; to $cellNum = 10; and $no_cell = ($cellNum + 1); to $no_cell = ($cellNum += 1);
thanks for your help @styl3r